# ConsenSys/eth-lightwallet - How does it work?

Tags: wallets, eth-lightwallet

I am using example webwallet.html from https://github.com/ConsenSys/eth-lightwallet

It seems to work for me but I am confused on how does it actually work. Can someone explain to me please?

Here is what  tried, in webwallet.html, I use localhost:8545 as host. I do not even connect my computer to internet. I give seed and password and I get 3 addresses.

Now from totally different computer I go to https://lightwallet.io, give the seed and password and I get the same 3 addresses as I saw in my local webwallet.html

I wonder how does other computer able to restore and get same 3 addresses?

Please can someone explain me how does this webwallet.html working?

Answer (score 3):

The lightwallet relies on Hierarchical Deterministic to derive the private keys. That means your 12 word seed is turned into a 128 bit master key. Now for every address you generate your private key by taking the master key and adding an incremental counter to the end.

- Address 1 -> Private Key = Master Key + 1 -> generate public Address from Private Key
- Address 2 -> Private Key = Master Key + 2 
  ...

This way you can always generate the same keys. Found this [explanation](http://support.mycelium.com/hc/en-us/articles/207045475-What-does-HD-in-HD-Wallet-mean-) from MyCellium quite helpful. It works the same for bitcoin or ethereum.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are able to type in a passphrase without even connecting to the internet and get 3 addresses in return is because ConsenSys implementes a Hierarchical Deterministic (HD) wallet. This means it is using an algorithm to convert passphrases into private keys. The algorithm always stays the same (it's *deterministic*) -online and offline- so no matter where you use their light wallet, your passphrase will always generate that same private key, enabling you to sign transactions through their client.

Answer (score 0):

I just added an answer because I can't comment I agree completely with t-Io's answer. 
I would just add this the [BIP32](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0032.mediawiki) standard as reference to check